# Calculate possible quantity from combination of available stock

Tags: excel, excel-formula, combinations, parent-child

I have this simple table of stock of fruit that can be used to create 3 type of drinks

[image]

How can I calculate how many drinks I can create from available stock of fruits and can it be done with an excel formula?

Comment: Yes, you can set that up in the Solver.

Comment: thanks for the solution, but it need to put qty of drinks manually. is there the way to do it automatically?

Comment: The quantity of drinks is calculated by the Solver based on the assumption of not running out of ingredients. If you change the numbers manually then when what you have used exceeds the stock available then you have a problem.

Comment: Ok i will try at home

Answer (score 0):

So, see the following implementation - had to move some bits:

[image]

Much more fun to add in some costs or selling prices and work out the number of the most expensive drinks or cheapest drinks etc etc

If you enter the numbers of drinks manually, then you can use conditional formatting to highlight the stock if the amount used exceeds the stock.